# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client

I am migrating my project from Java EE 7 to Jakarta EE 10.0.0 and have changed all the relvant javax references to jakarta.

I have no any compilation issues but I am getting the following error during runtime.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider for jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder cannot be found.

Following are the dependencies I use in my project. I added jersey-client and jersey-media-json-jackson to fix the ClientBuilder issue.

I have implmented my ClientBuilder as below

```
CLIENT = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature.class).build();
```

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile.config</groupId>
                <artifactId>microprofile-config-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
                <version>19.20.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: You need to mark the dependencies already provided by target runtime (i.e. the server) as `provided` otherwise you may end up having duplicate instances of them. Having the `jakarta.jakartaee-api` as runtime dependency of a WAR project makes absolutely no sense. So at least that one should at set to `provided`. Others are unclear because information about target runtime is absent in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the below dependencies and changing the client builder implementation to

CLIENT = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient();

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
```